# distinct eigenvalues implies $\dim(E_{\lambda_i}) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

as the title states: why does distinct eigenvalues imply that geometric multiplicity of all those eigenvalues is 1?

This is used by diagonalization, but it just states it without actually proving anything. Any help on intuition?

Comment: What is $\sum_i \dim(E_{\lambda_i})$?

Comment: I would say $n$, because that is what you want to hear. But why?

Comment: why can't it be more than $n$?

Comment: "Distinct" means only one eigenvector per eigenvalue.

Comment: It's not what I wanted to hear, it's what comes out at the end. Let's start a little simpler, what is $\dim(E_{\lambda_1}) + \dim(E_{\lambda_2})$, and how is it related to $E_{\lambda_1} + E_{\lambda_2}$?

Comment: well $\dim(E_{\lambda_1})$ can at most only be one, and it has atleast one vector, so the summation should be 2. its relation to $E_{\lambda_1}+E_{\lambda_2}$ ? a union of the vecotrs in those eigenspaces? the dimension is 2 again?

Comment: $\dim(E_{\lambda_1}) + \dim(E_{\lambda_2}) = \dim (E_{\lambda_1} + E_{\lambda_2}) + \dim (E_{\lambda_1} \cap E_{\lambda_2})$. Now, $E_{\lambda_1}$ and $E_{\lambda_2}$ are eigenspaces for different eigenvalues. What does that tell you about the intersection?

Comment: $\emptyset$ I would assume? - christ, the emptyset symbol is ugly. Because they describe different spaces?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like what you are reading says something like "Suppose an $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues," and in *that* case yes, this means they are pairwise distinct, and hence they only occur once each.

If the author left out "n" from "n distinct," then the next best guess would be that they meant "no repeated eigenvalues."

Comment: I understand the n distinct eigenvalues, as it is bound by the matrix it is in, but I'm talking about the geometric multiplicity, why is it bound to $n$? As Daniel Fischer Implied

Comment: @WiseStrawberry The geometric multiplicity is always less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity, and because the eigenvalues are distinct, they all have algebraic multiplicity one. This means the geometric multiplicity is bounded above and below by 1.

Comment: Less than or equal right?

Comment: @WiseStrawberry yes, you're right, and I edited the comment to include "or equal"

Comment: makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're talking about an $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues: the big thing here is that eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

To see why: call your matrix $A$. Suppose that $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are nonzero $\lambda_1$- and $\lambda_2$-eigenvectors, respectively, where $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$. If $a_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\vec{v}_2=\vec{0}$ for some $a_1$ and $a_2$, then we have
$$
\vec{0}=A(a_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\vec{v}_2)=a_1\lambda_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\lambda_2\vec{v}_2
$$
and
$$
\vec{0}=\lambda_1(a_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\vec{v}_2)=a_1\lambda_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\lambda_1\vec{v}_2.
$$
Combining these yields $a_2(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\vec{v}_2=\vec{0}$; since $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ and $\vec{v}_2\neq\vec{0}$, this implies $a_2=0$. From here, it is not too hard to show that $a_1=0$ as well, so that the vectors are linearly independent as claimed.

So, if $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are your eigenvalues, and $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$ are associated eigenvectors, then $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$ are linearly independent vectors... and since there are $n$ of them, they must be a basis!

Comment: This helps in understanding why they are linearly indpendent, but my problemw as the fact that there could not be $n$ of them. But I know see that this is the case.